# Which query has a better performance?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-performance

```
SELECT *
FROM { SELECT * FROM BigMillionTable UNION ALL SELECT * FROM SmallTensTable } 
WHERE (some_condition)
```

Vs

```
SELECT * 
FROM BigMillionTable 
WHERE (some_condition)

UNION ALL

SELECT * 
FROM SmallTensTable
WHERE (some_condition)
```

My questions:

1. Does the first query need to put all the rows in the
   `BigMillionTable` in the main memory to perform `UNION ALL` ?
2. Which query provides better performance ?

Comment: What happened when you tried? But I would be very surprised if Oracle chose to use different execution plans for those two statements.

Comment: Compare the explain plans. Any difference?

Comment: The first query has much better performance because it fails immediately due to the curly  braces syntax error. After fixing it Oracle will most probably unnest the subquery and you will see the same [execution plan.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975406/how-to-describe-performance-issue-in-relational-database)

Comment: There is a nice article on Sigmod 2018 related to the TeraData on this topic. You should read it: http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~meltabakh/Publications/UnionAll-Demo-SIGMOD-2018.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The where condition is actually executed before the select, so in the 2nd query you are only doing a union all on a smaller set, so that should be faster.

In the 1st query, the inner query will run first, which will do a union all on the whole table and then the where would be executed before selecting the records.

So yes, 2nd would provide better performance compared to the 1st one

Comment: Your advice could match for some RDBMS or even for some antique release of Oracle. Tecent versions can perform *query transformation* to avoid such  problems, so you should test it and provide evidence about the difference before posting it.

Comment: Even the query transformation takes that extra bit of time, which the 2nd query will not face

Comment: @SushantSharma . . . I would expect the Oracle optimizer to be smart enough to push the filtering conditions into the `union all` subqueries.   That is one thing done by databases with good optimizers.

Comment: That periscopedata link should be banned - it's very misleading